# How to set Docker Backing Filesystem to XFS?

Tags: mongodb, docker, storage, xfs

I'm having difficulty setting up Docker to build a container with the XFS Filesystem. My Storage Driver is correctly set to `overlay2`, but my Backing Filesystem is `extfs`.

Is there something I would specify for `storage-opts` in my docker daemon file?

Comment: Hi Nick, 
Have you resolved the warning ? Could you share your solution ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using the `overlay2` storage driver, then Docker never creates filesystems. It is simply creating directories on your existing backing filesystem.  If that filesystem is using `ext4`, that's what you're going to get.

The only situation in which Docker actually creates a new filesystem is when using the `devicemapper` driver, in which case Docker is carving out chunks from a block storage device and then formatting them for use with the filesystem of your choice.

Comment: Ah understood. Would you recommend I use `devicemapper` over `overlay2` in order to resolve the following warning from a dockerized mongodb instance:
`** WARNING: Using the XFS filesystem is strongly recommended with the WiredTiger storage engine
**          See http://dochub.mongodb.org/core/prodnotes-filesystem`

Comment: I would just ensure that `/var/lib/docker` is a dedicated filesystem, format that with XFS, and continue to use the `overlay2` storage driver.  It's generally more performant than `devicemapper`.

Comment: It means that you cannot choose the filesystem of docker. It chooses for you based on your storage driver?

Comment: You can obviously select which filesystem you use for the backing store of the `overlay2` driver, but you cannot select the filesystem used individually by each container.